# SSRS 2008 passing multiple parameters Oracle 10g backend

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ora-01722

after several years of using Cognos, we are in process of testing conversion of Cognos Reports (8.3) to SSRS 2008 reports.  we use Oracle database version 10g.  in many of our reports we are converting we pass multiple values in parameters, however i cannot get this working in SSRS pointing to the Oracle datasource.

i have created parameter and set it to allow multiple values.  these columns are integer types.  the SQL filter is set as follows for example, where vendor_id IN (:Vendor_id).  yet when I test the SQL, i get errors.  i enter parameter values as comma-seperated for example, 102, 105, 107.  errors as follows.

ORA-01722: invalid number

i've tried wrapping value in single, double quotes with same result.  is there a different format to meet oracle syntax requirement?  does multiple values only work for SQL server databases?

thanks in advance.
joe

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in this post, multi value parameters are concatenated and used as follows:

Select * from Table WHERE column1 in (:CommaSeparatedListOfValues)

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/stevewright/archive/2009/08/14/14763.aspx

So Vendor_id has to be Varchar2. I guess you have the data type of Vendor_id as integer?.

Comment: Correct.  The values for Vendor_id in the db is integer.  Thank you for the response.  I will review and post a follow up here.